# publish_action permission in facebook for desktop application

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, desktop-application

I have a desktop application(WPF) that post photo to the user's facebook wall. but now as per new grap API of facebook requires publish_action permission for appId. I want to submit my application for this permission but there is no option for desktop application(WPF) in facebook graph API.So how can i get this permission for desktop application(WPF).?How i can proceed my application for review process of facebook?is there any other way to post photo on facebook user's wall from desktop application(WPF).? when i post photo it always give response exception of type #200 permission error from facebook API.So this is blocking issue for me.Thanks in advance.please help me!!!

Comment: you have to fill the Review Submission Form first in your app settings , did you ?

Comment: but in platform selection(windows,android,etc),there is not any option for desktop app submission.? is there any way to submit app for desktop.?

Comment: just select a Website.

Comment: @EslamHamouda..Thanks for reply... but when i select website as platform it ask for url of website facebook page. in case of desktop application how i can give url for submission.???

Comment: After 8 months of trying I have the same problem. There is even no way to  contact the technical support.